# Having trouble using javascript to create dynamic URL's with django for dates

Tags: django

Currently I have two basic routes:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('<int:tutor_id>/', views.tutorHomeOverviewPage, name='tutorHomeOverviewPage'), 
    path('<int:tutor_id>/<str:selected_date>/', views.tutorSelectedDay, name='tutorSelectedDay'),
]
```

These routes point to two views which just get data from the database and send it to the template.

The views work without any issues.

My issue seems to lie with the URL that is being created in my JS files.

So I have a calendar that dynamically gets list elements from a javascript for days that look like this:

```
<a href="2022-10-14" id="day14">14</a>
```

When I am at the URL - `http://127.0.0.1:8000/tutorhomepage/7/` (which matches the first URL path) and I click on one of the days (so let's say the anchor element above), it goes to the correct URL: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/tutorhomepage/7/2022-10-14/`

However, when I click on another day while at `http://127.0.0.1:8000/tutorhomepage/7/2022-10-14/`, it just adds a second date to the URL like so - `http://127.0.0.1:8000/tutorhomepage/7/2022-10-14/2022-10-1`

My javascript, which is creating the `'a href'` links, looks like this in brief:

```
aLink.setAttribute('href',  currentYear + '-' + (currentMonth + 1) + '-' +dayCounter)
```

Any idea why this is happening and a possible fix for it?

Comment: You are building a relative path which automatically appends to the path of the current page. I suggest building an absolute path from the root of your server.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice, any docs or advice on how to do that, this is a hobby project ,not really a programmer lol

Comment: I suggest you start by reading about the difference between a relative path and an absolute path. Google these terms to get some info.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice, i see what you are saying man and ty for the help I fixed it via - aLink.setAttribute('href', 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/tutorhomepage/7/' + currentYear + '-' + (currentMonth + 1) + '-' +dayCounter).

Is that the best way to do it in your opinion, or should I add a json_script variable in the html file for a url template, then pull the data from there? No idea which is best practice or even if second idea is possible lol

Comment: You bring up a good point. I would probably do this using a `{% url %}` tag in the django template.